# how to add dynamic field to existing collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a mongodb collection called products in which I have fields (id, name, price and properties) and now different products have different kind of properties for example iphone has different set of properties when compared to nike shoes. So how to define a schema and add dynamically new key and value pair using mongoose.

```
{
  "_id":"001",
  "name":"iphone 5",
  "price":$650,
  "properties":{
    'weight':2.3, 
    'talktime': '8 hours', 
    'battery type': 'lithium'
  }
}


{
  "_id":"002",
  "name":"nike shoes",
  "price":$80,
  "properties":{
    'size':10, 
    'color':black
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at Mongoose's Mixed schema type: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html.  If you specify that type for an attribute (`{}`) it will allow anything to be saved to it.

For example:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    price: String,
    properties: {}
});
mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);


var Product = mongoose.model("Product");
var product = new Product({
    "name": "iphone 5",
    "price": "$650",
    "properties": {
        "weight": 2.3,
        "talktime": "8 hours",
        "battery type": "lithium"
    }
});
product.save();
```

After running the code above, the database now contains this document:

```
{
    "name" : "iphone 5",
    "price" : "$650",
    "properties" : {
        "battery type" : "lithium",
        "talktime" : "8 hours",
        "weight" : 2.3
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b35ca575e9d7a40de0edb7"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but what if I want to embed the sub-document. for eg:
 product.anything={id:001, name:"", desc:"",
                   properties:{size:"9", weight:"1.4", display:"4.7"}
}
is it possible to do in this way and I even want to add the key and value of properties from front end, is that possible?

Comment: @Yash I've updated the answer to hopefully align better with your question. Does using the mixed schema type as a solution make more sense with this updated answer?

Comment: Hi, this isn't working for me.  My model is Tournament with a property called "rounds" which is empty {} like your example.
I set an express route POST request: tournament.rounds.roundOne = [], tournament.rounds.roundTwo = [], etc.
It's only working if I actually define `roundOne: {}, roundTwo: {}` in the Schema, but that defeats the purpose